# What is "Stotterlaut" in the phonetics?

Tags: meaning, phonetics, consonant-sounds

What is "Stotterlaut"? Is this term used in the phonetics? If so, what sound exactly does it indicate? I guess that it might belong to one of the plosive or affricate sounds from the context, but I couldn't find any definition or enough reference. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you encounter that word? A source would be nice.

Comment: It was used in the context that unlike Phoenician there were no "Zischlaut, Knacklaut and Stotterlaut" in Ancient Greek.

Answer (score 5):

Stotterlaut itself is the sound you make when you stutter (literally stutter noise). [This article](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/moszkows/sprache/chap019.html) mentions

> Nun ist d nicht nur Verschluß-, Dental-Laut, sondern wie die Erfahrung ergibt, bei häufiger Wiederholung geradezu ein Stotterlaut

My translation:

> Now *d* is not  only a plosive and dental sound, but as experience shows downright a stutter sound, when frequently repeated

This is illustrated with some examples, among which is the following

> Die, die die Didaktik Diderots zum Gegenstand ihrer Studien machten [...]

The beginning of the sentence, which causes you to say /di/ 4 times, sounds like a stuttering person trying to say *Didaktik*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Still I wonder whether "Stotterlaut" is a phonetical term or not.. As far as I can understand from the passage you mentions, the word Stotterlaut is used in its literal meaning, stutter noise as you explained, whereas for the other two, Verschluß-Laut and Dental-Laut, I could easily follow that they are Plosivlaut and Zahnlaut in the phonetical terms...